# Custom Bottom Navigation Bar Item (extract as widget)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bottom-navigation-bar

How can I extract BottomNavigationBarItem in order to have a more readable code and reuse the item widget?

If I extract them in a Stateless Widget I get an error:

> can't be assigned to the list type 'BottomNavigationBarItem'

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
              height: 56,
              width: 56,
              child: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
            ),
            label: '')
```

I know I could extract the Container inside the icon property, but I'd like to extract the whole Widget.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For creating any method for the particular widget , you need to define return type of that item.eg.

```
class CommonWidget{

BottomNavigationBarItem getItem(){
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
              height: 56,
              width: 56,
              child: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
            ),
            label: '');
   }

}
```

And you can call this getItem inside your Bottom Navigation item List.

Comment: Ok I managed to use it and add some parameters I needed. Thanks a lot!